# “Odd” method of determening area of a triangle using (no trigonometry)

Tags: geometry

While learning some basic programming, I came across a (to me) very strange method of calculating the area of a triangle. 
In Javascript, this was expressed as:

```
var perimeter = (side1 + side2 + side3)/2;  
var area =  Math.sqrt(perimeter*((perimeter-side1)*(perimeter-side2)*(perimeter-side3)));
```

This can be mathematically represented as following: 
$$A_\triangle=\sqrt{d\Biggl(( d-a )(d-b)(d-c) \Biggr) }$$
where $d$ equals to half of the sum of the length of the three sides of the triangle, and $a$, $b$, and $c$ represent the three different lengths respectively.

I cannot, either by expanding or just 'looking' at the equation, figure out *why* this works (I *assume* it does so after testing with a few example triangles).

If any kind (and clever) soul could explain why this works, It'd much appreciated.

Comment: Definitely a duplicate - thanks for the heads up! I had no clue that it was referred to as Heron's formula.

Comment: It's not odd at all: it's *Heron's formula* named after *Hero of Alexandria*, a Greek mathematician from the 1st century.

Comment: @Bernard so I have understood, and hence marked the question as a duplicate :) The community here is truly great, being so nice despite me posting a question which evidently has been posted multiple times before! Much appreciated.